# GeoServer layers: Default value for extra values showing up even when other value is provided

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs

I've got a PostGIS table that I'm publishing using GeoServer (2.21.1). I have multiple overlapping vector layers for different classes. I've also got an aggregate class included that is the average of all the other vector classes and I want that to be the default option. This works fine.

HOWEVER!

When I use CQL to provide an alternate to the default I end up a SQL query that tries to select items from the PostGIS table where class = 'Default' and class = 'Alternate'. Obviously this returns nothing, which is unexpected.

Here's the config for the layer:

[image: Geoserver settings]

and then I do a CQL query on the layer preview:
[image]

which returns a blank map after I hit "apply". The SQL that pops up in the log file is:

```
SELECT 
  <a bunch of columns>
WHERE (
"month" = 'Average' 
AND "month" IS NOT NULL  
AND "type" = 'Fishing'
AND "type" IS NOT NULL 
AND "type" = 'All'  
AND <a bunch of other filters>
```

Is there any way to fix this? Is this a misconfiguration (or misunderstanding on my part) or is this a legit bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for misunderstanding. WMS dimensions and CQL filters are not in an "override" relationship, they are two orthogonal filters instead.

The dimension is always there, and will always be applied once configured (as per standard), the optional CQL_FILTER parameter always acts on top of it.

If you want to select `type=Fishing` use the dimension query mechanism instead, adding `&DIM_type=Fishing`. This is an actual override of the default dimension value.

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. Thanks!